# Multiple Macs and the OS X Lion Hardware Up-to-Date Program?

Tags: macos, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which new Mac purchasers get free upgrades to 10.7?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9451/which-new-mac-purchasers-get-free-upgrades-to-10-7)

I'm due for a free update to Mac OS X Lion, as I bought an iMac in July after the cut-off date for free updates.

When I go to claim the free update on the apple web site, it asks me to enter the serial numbers of all "qualifying macs". If I just enter the number of the Mac that I bought most recently, will I be able to install Lion on the other ones manually? I assume so, but I don't want to accidentally short myself $30 :)

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't entering all the serial numbers as directed? If you mess up - you can always reach out to the store support through a billing inquiry, but enter all the numbers before the cutoff date to ensure you hold up your end of the deal.

Comment: The other macs were bought 6+ months ago - I'm not sure whether I should enter them there, or whether I shouldn't bother because as soon as one mac has Lion, I can just put it on all my other ones.

Comment: Also one is 30 minutes drive away, so I can't get the serial number for it easily. :)

Comment: Just collect the sales receipts of all the macs you bought since [July 21](http://www.apple.com/macosx/uptodate/) - you have 30 days after purchase to request your license. Technically you can install one download onto many macs - like all the past OS X - you aren't forced to validate things so it shouldn't be a problem as long as each mac gets a license before you install.

Comment: @bmike - That's the thing, only one was bought after July 21st. I think that still means I get a copy that I can install on my other macs, right?

Comment: Yes, you can install it, but you shouldn't without a proper license. Why don't you call apple ( 800-692-7753 "1-800-MY-APPLE") and see if they can sort it out - you might find them to be very accommodating if you messed up the claim windows and are trying to do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

The download of Lion, like any other App on the Mac App Store is subject to the same licensing counts as any other app. You are able to have 5 simultaneous copies of the App just like you can authorize 5 machines to hold your iTunes purchased content.

Comment: There is no concept of limited computer authorization in the Mac App Store. If you successfully login with your Apple ID, you have access to anything you've downloaded from the store.